# Direct access PCI serial port

Tags: c++, c, windows, serial-port

Hello i have an application built some times ago in C++.

It is used to control an appliance via serial port.

I remember the guy that developed it saying that his software is directly accessing the serial port (directly accessing the memory).

Since PCs with serial ports are becoming rare these days, would the software still directly access the serial port if i used a PCI extension serial port?

Thanks

Comment: Most likely the driver of the PCI card will allow the OS to report the serial port as a "normal" serial port.

Comment: Agree with Joachim, even the USB<->Serial converters usually load a driver that presents the serial port as "COM#" port.  With a COM port, you don't need to worry about direct-memory access because you can use regular Win32 file system calls: CreateFile, OpenFile, WriteFile, ReadFile, CloseFile (and of course the async "*Ex" equivalents if needed).  You might have to translate the software somewhat, but that should be straight forward.  There are tons of resources on the web for accessing COM ports...

Answer (score 1):

That depends a bit on how much backward-compatible driver support your PCIe serial port has.

If it provides direct I/O-space mapping of a (possibly virtual) [16550 UART](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/16550_UART)'s [registers](http://www.lammertbies.nl/comm/info/serial-uart.html#regs), you will need to change the "base address" in the software but then it might work. If the drivers do not, then it's not going to work.

The first four standard serial ports have the following base addresses and interrupts associated with them:

```
     | base   IRQ 
-----------------
COM1 | 0x3f8  IRQ4
COM2 | 0x2f8  IRQ3
COM3 | 0x3e8  n/a
COM4 | 0x2e8  n/a
```

The software should probably be rewritten to use more high-level access to the port.

Comment: So if the driver provides direct I/O space mapping the software will not need to access the serial port through the PCI driver?
Windows 32bit will always keep a part of the addressable memory for I/O operation. How does the driver instruct the OS to map a part of the memory for the serial port?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the vast majority of [local bus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_bus) serial port cards emulate a [16x50 RS-232 UART](http://www.pccompci.com/uarts.html). Unless you intend to use some special card, such as those expensive multiport cards used for managing modem banks, it would probably be fine.

[USB/RS-232 converters](http://www.lammertbies.nl/comm/info/RS-232-usb.html) are a different story altogether - in general they will not work with software that accesses the serial port directly, as their driver only provides access via the OS serial port subsystem. Even if their driver somehow manages to emulate a proper local bus UART, those converters often have different behavior w.r.t. signal timing that might lead to issues with software that does unusual things with the serial port. For example, I have had issues with attaching [IR remote control receivers](http://www.lirc.org/receivers.html) to some USB/RS-232 converters. Using a converter that supports [USB 2.0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Serial_Bus#USB_2.0) helps somewhat, but it is still far from the real thing.

You should also keep in mind that if your application is designed for an older OS, newer versions of that operating system might not allow direct access to serial ports anymore.

If all else fails, you might still be able to improve the situation by using a virtual machine. For example, [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#serialports) allows the guest OS to access the host serial ports, emulating a 16550A UART. This might allow you to work around a driver or an OS that does not support or allow direct access to a serial port.

Answer (score 0):

I searched around i found some PCI cards that map their serial ports to the memory.
I will try one of those.

Thank you all.

Answer (score -2):

I have another solution.
PCs are coming with mostly usb ports.
so you can use any usb to serial port converter. it is very cheap and works fine.

Comment: I thought of that but it still raises the same question will the application be able to directly access the serial port? In the case of usb i don't think that is possible. It will have to go through the emulation driver. + you can not access the USB port by writing directly on the memory.

Comment: driver with that converter will do all this you don't have to worry about intermediate steps. It will work exactly as your serial port was working. I had used it. The only problem that occurred was that data transfer got slow.

Comment: Windows uses usbser.sys for the USB CDC class.
Every communication with the emulated serial port will have to go through that driver that's why your communication got slower. It added an extra layer between you app and the serial port.

Comment: @Rizstien That is only true if you access the device through official APIs, not directly(either through IO ports or memory mapps) as seems to be the case of the OP here